# Scroll down/top and position a div to the center of the screen

Tags: css, vue.js, scroll

[image]

I'm using Vue and I have the following case on a web app on mobile. I have 2 cards and the second card is showing just aproximately 10% of its height. When the user scrolls down to about half of the second card, I want to scroll down so that the second card is placed instead of card 1. And then repeat the process. The reverse way when the user scrolls up.

Is there any way I could find when half of the second card is showing ? And then move it instead of the first card?

I tried to use translate, but that will not work because it will leave empty space on top of the cards.
I tried looking when the user finishes touching the screen, take the vertical scroll position and move the scroll to a specific position, but this a bit hard-coded and is not going to work if the cards have different heights.

Comment: You can use an [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to determine element visibility, along with [flex order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property) perhaps

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: This sounds like [scroll snapping](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/).